# how to over come elevation error in using pip in python

Tags: python, pip

i was trying to install a particular module in python using command prompt. [c:>pip install django](https://youtu.be/2E3RDgsoykY)

it is showing some **fatal error in launcher. the operation requires elevation.**

I tried from idle

```
>>> pip install django
```

it showing syntax error.
how to over come this?

Comment: Did you trying right-clicking command prompt, and selecting **Run As Administrator**?

Comment: Can you please share the error message and the steps followed. Also, what operating system are we talking about? Windows? Mac? Since its c:\> i assume windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+syntaxerror

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have permission, you can run it as `pip` only for current user:

```sh
python -m pip install --user django
```

You cannot run `pip install` that way in idle. To do that you will do something like:

```
>>>import subprocess
>>>import sys

>>> subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--user", "django"])
```

If you don’t want to install as user, then you have elevate the current user to have `sudo` or Administrator rights to elimate the Error `to fatal error in launcher. the operation requires elevation.`

Comment: Note that pip can be imported itself, so using subprocess isn't completely necessary

Comment: I know that method too. But I usually discourage Idle way of installation